# Where in Alat (Azerbaijan) is the bus stop for transport heading to Baku?

Tags: public-transport, buses, taxis, azerbaijan, baku

I'll be arriving at the Alat port on a Ferry from Kazakhstan, and Need to go to Baku from there.

Is there a bus stop at the port? If not, how far is the nearest stop from the port?

If I take a taxi, I Need to know the approximate distance to the nearest bus stop so I don't get overcharged.

I have read this guide http://caravanistan.com/transport/caspian-sea-ferry/

However it only says "In Alat there should be buses going to the port (or a taxi – it is only a short distance)."

Does anyone know whether there are in fact buses directly at the port? If yes, what does it cost in total yo Baku? If not, how far from the port is the neareest bus stop

Comment: If you have read and understood [this guide](http://caravanistan.com/transport/caspian-sea-ferry/), and there are still questions left open, please indicate so in your question.

Comment: Some info here: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ferries_in_the_Caspian_Sea

Comment: Says the same Thing...

Comment: One good reference for this stuff (marshrutka/bus stop locations) is usually the Lonely Planet guidebook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Caravanistan guide](http://caravanistan.com/transport/caspian-sea-ferry/) that you cite describes getting from Baku to Alat but it is not too hard to backtrack:

- from Alat port take a minibus / taxi to the bus stop
- from there take bus 195 to Baku

Looking at google maps, [this](https://goo.gl/maps/7VqSJsdeHvj) seems to be the Alat port to me. You are looking for transportation from the port to the bus stop where the 195 will take you to Baku.
Google directions public transport feat does have the stops of that bus (and also the schedule) and the nearest one to the port (and most logical for minibuses etc.) seems to be [the one by the Alat train station](https://goo.gl/maps/tNkcd7qH5V52).

Driving distance between the port and the bus stop should be some 3km or 10 mins (maps is missing a street there so these are my guesses).

[The Lonely Planet confirms this and gives price indications](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/azerbaijan/baku-to-qobustan/transport/transportation-travel-services/new-baku-international-seaport):

> A taxi to/from Baku should cost around AZN30. Alternatively take bus 195 (80q): after passing through Baș Ələt, get off by the big roundabout, from where waiting taxis charge AZN5 for the last 3km.